# Formatting strings in JAVA with Android Studio

Tags: java, android, string

I am trying to format a specific string. I had the unfortunate event of my laptop crashing on me the other day, taking away with it lots of valuable code. I did save most of the files, but the few that weren't saved were crucial to my android app. Well Here is my code that tries to format a string. I need all the numbers at the beginning of each line to go away. there are about 3600 of them.

```
//inside onCreate method
String string = "3    import android.animation.Animator; \n" +
"4    import android.animation.AnimatorListenerAdapter; \n" +
"5    import android.animation.ValueAnimator; \n" +
"6    import android.app.Activity; \n" +
"7    import android.content.Context; \n" +
"8    import android.content.DialogInterface; \n";

char[] ch = string.toCharArray();
    char c ='M';


    for(int i=4;i<ch.length;i++){
        boolean b1 = false;
        boolean b2 = false;
        boolean b3 = false;
        boolean b4 = false;
        c = ch[i];
        if((c >= '0' && c <= '9') && (ch[i-1]=='\n')){
            b1 = true;

            if((ch[i+1] >= '0' && ch[i+1] <= '9'))b2=true;

            if((ch[i+2] >= '0' && ch[i+2] <= '9'))b3=true;}

        if(b1)ch[i]='Q';
        if(b2)ch[i+1]='Q';
        if(b3)ch[i+2]='Q';

        b1 = false;
        b2 = false;
        b3 = false;
    }

    String strings = ch.toString();
    strings.replace("Q","");

    Log.d("meoww","juy "+strings);
```

As you can see, the for loop tries to get rid of these numbers for me. The logs
show the following output:

```
juy [C@3d03b1f5
```

I know its probably a minor error, but how can I correct this. Like I say, I will have to do this about 3600 inside this for loop.

thanks for any suggestions,

Keep on coding

Comment: Use `String.valueOf()` instead of toString()

Comment: If it's showing something like `[C@3d03b1f5` that means it's displaying the address of the object and not the contents inside...just saying

Comment: Try `String strings = new String(ch);` instead of `String strings = ch.toString();`

Answer (score 1):

This code

`String.replaceAll ("^\d*\s", " ")`  this will take numbers at the beginning of the line `^` following by one of more digit `\d*` followed by a space and replace this with a space

Comment: This probably will do the trick. I will upvote it as soon as i test it out. Hope it doesn't remove crital numbers used in array or for loop construction. @Scary Wombat

Answer (score 0):

try this:
`String str = string.replaceAll("[0-9]","");`

This will remove all digits.

Comment: It will remove all digits from the strings, so may it remove any digit present in the code also???

Comment: It will replace all digits from String with empty values. So yes.

Comment: I cant have the digits that are used in new arrays, for loops and alpha-numeric variable names removed. @Vygintas B

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
      {// inside onCreate method
        String string = "3    import android.animation.Animator; \n"
            + "4    import android.animation.AnimatorListenerAdapter; \n"
            + "5    import android.animation.ValueAnimator; \n" + "6    import android.app.Activity; \n"
            + "7    import android.content.Context; \n" + "8    import android.content.DialogInterface; \n"
            + "17    import android.content.Context; \n" + "558    import android.content.DialogInterface; \n";

        char[] ch = string.toCharArray();
        if(ch[0] > '0' && ch[0] < '9'){
          ch[0] = ' ';
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++)
        {
          if (ch[i] == '\n')
          {
            int count = i + 1;
            if (count < ch.length)
            {
              while (count < ch.length && ch[count] >= '0' && ch[count] <= '9')
              {
                ch[count] = ' ';
                count++;
              }
            }
          }
        }

        String strings = new String(ch);

        System.out.println(strings);
      }
```

This code will replace number at first position of each line with space. After this you can apply eclipse formatter to remove unnecessary spaces.